# How to determine whether transformation is linear and finding its matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the transformation T from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by
$$T[x_1, x_2]=x_1[1,2,3]+x_2[4,5,6].$$

Is the transformation linear? If so, find its matrix.

How would I determine whether the transformation is linear and then go about obtaining its matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is an $m$-by-$n$ matrix with columns $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then 
$$ Ax := \sum_{i=1}^n x_i a_i.$$

Thus, the transformation $T$ above is, by definition, a matrix transformation (and, hence, a linear transformation) and 
$$T(x) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 \\
2 & 5 \\
3 & 6
\end{bmatrix} x,
$$ 
with 
$$ x = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2. $$